# Apache Solr and customized field filter for search

Tags: regex, filter, solr

in my schema i have a field (salary) which is actually a string, because it can be anything (fetched from some websites): only numbers, strings, no numbers at all. Basically, anything. What i know about that field is that if there are numbers, i need to extract them, do maybe some manipulation (basic operations, actually) and use the result in my searches.

How can i accomplish that? Can i define my custom function and then call it with the {!func}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) it should be sufficient. If it is not sufficient you can implement of course a custom FilterFactory which does the job.

Comment: thanks, i'll try with custom filtering and pattern replace, that should make it